# Is there a way to select block of code in Visual studio just by double click like in Eclipse?

Tags: visual-studio

In Eclipse you can double click next to an open brace and that selects the block of code, however in Visual Studio you need to press the `CTRL+SHIF+]`! How can i edit this shortcut so that simply a double click does the same thing? (holding too many keys is just too much)

Comment: Have you looked at tools like Resharper?

Comment: Reshaper is costly, I thought I could override default shortcuts

Answer (score 3):

To change how the text editor interacts with the mouse, you'll have to develop a Visual Studio extension. Or, you can just change the keyboard shortcut to perform this action to whatever you like. You can do this from Tools/Options/Environment/Keyboard and select the command `Edit.GotoBraceExtend`. Enter the new shortcut in `Press shortcut keys` by pressing them then click `Assign` and `OK`.

[image]

Note that if the shortcut you have selected was assigned to some other command, the assignment will change.

Comment: Note: This is language specific. For example, in German you need to search for `Bearbeiten.ErweiternbisKlammer`. For whatever reason it wasn't enough to make this language specific but they also had to garble up the word order and camel case. Mildly annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Try ctl+m+m anywhere in the code block. This will collapse the code accordingly and then you can copy